# Woocommerce Product Navigation should not show next category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce plugin and i have woocommerce product navigation link plugin to navigate inside products...

I want to have show the product navigation only inside the category.. Currently its is showing navigation to all the products.. i.e., if one category is completed then it is showing the navigation button to the next product in the next category.. here is my Code i have in the `woocommerce-product-navigation.php` file ..

Here's the [Eval](https://eval.in/441964)

What is the mistake i am doing and i can i get it ?

```
   $output  = '<div class="wpn_buttons ' . $wpn_custom_class .'">'; 
    if ( $previous != '' )
        $output .= '<span class="next"> ' . $previous . '</span>';
    if ( $next != '' )
        $output .= ' <span class="previous">' . $next .'</span>';
    $output .= '</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider the hooks and write some function to filter the contents something like if category is changed exit .I guess you should use `woocommerce_before_single_product` hook .

Comment: Can you pls tell little bit clear.because i am new to this.. thanks sir

Comment: First you can use my name do not need to use Sir, what I have tried to say is before displaying the product try to get the category of that product or use category to display product belongs to those category .

Comment: Thanks :)  I will try and convey you

Comment: I will see the plugin I have already downloaded .If It will be not solved I will try and let you know.